# Passing data from one view to another in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

I am trying to load a view with custom message in it. So here is the scenario

Let say I am on index and I am going to navigate to index2.html.

Index2.html will render the custom message passed to it. One way is definitely to do it with **$routeParams** but I don't what to pass the information through the url, rather I want it in a general POST format where passed data is not exposed in url

Also I don't want to use localstorage, session or cookie. 
I want it in a way where I pass the data to the view and it should get rendered.

If anyone can help me with this

Comment: You can pass through localstorage, session or cookie

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without using session, localstorage or cookie as I want to do it passing data

Comment: from my point of view you can achieve this by sending data to server through post and rendering to next page

Comment: here Navigation reload the whole page? or inject html to the same page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FACTORY** - The right way to share data between pages is a factory/service.

In this example I'll show you how to share data between two controllers, But it's the same thing. Once you invoke the service you have access to his instance and his data.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 
myApp.factory('shareService', function(){
    return {
        title: "some title"
    };
});

myApp.controller('controller1', function($scope, shareService){    
    var ctrl1 = this;
    ctrl1.title = shareService.title;
});

myApp.controller('controller2', function($scope, shareService){
    var ctrl2 = this;
    ctrl2.title = shareService.title;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="controller1 as ctrl1">
        {{ctrl1.title}}        
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="controller2 as ctrl2">
        {{ctrl2.title}}
    </div>    
</div>
```

Read more about services on [AngularJs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

**UPDATE**

A working example for routing and shared data on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gBwzCDa0rXt4ZTR9b21E?p=preview)

Comment: here factory data will reset while navigating to another page.

Comment: @AbbasGaliyakot It will work for navigation also because angular framework. See my update on my answer.

Comment: you have use $routeProvider which will inject page 1 and page 2 in a index page, it means page is not reloaded. if this is the scenario then same can be achieved by $rootscope

Comment: Is the author of the question said something about refresh or reload?

Comment: no dear but i sense it to be in this way.. thanks.. upvoted

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Dvir

Comment: $rootscope was helpful @AbbasGaliyakot .. thanks a lot